# Craft CMS can not save a specific entry

Tags: php, mysql, yii

On a fresh CraftCMS installation, after creating the entry type, I can not save a specific entry, it returns an MySQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'structureId' doesn't have a default value. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `craft_structureelements` (`uid`, `lft`, `rgt`, `level`, `root`, `dateUpdated`, `dateCreated`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6). Bound with :yp0='c4445686-1fb3-4e30-a449-a5c4c8865379', :yp1='1', :yp2='2', :yp3=0, :yp4=NULL, :yp5='2018-04-02 08:02:42', :yp6='2018-04-02 08:02:42'
```

This happens only a on the "Gas stations" entry type, not on others (others work fine). Here are the fields used:

- Title (by default)
- Gas Prices - table with 3 rows and 2 cols
- Address - basic text field (with breaks allowed)
- open times - text field
- description - text field \w breaks
- services - checkbox group (with default values)
- photos - assets, allowing only images

this should work fine (I did similar things many times), I did not change anything in the source code, not even got to templating. I already googled a while, but nothing useful came up.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: From the error message, the problem seems pretty obvious. The column referenced as ```:yp4``` (column `root`) is set to null. Look at the schema of the table. That column does not allow nulls, and no default value for the column is set. When a column is defined in that way, you can't set it's value to null. You will need to either change the definition of the column to allow nulls, or ensure the data inserted or updated isn't null.

Comment: Craft does not allow you to save anything that is set to required, also everything had a value when I was saving. Also I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so as it happens when you post the question, after a while, you will find out the answer:

when you make a structure on Craft, you can not set the max levels to 0, the lowest value is 1.